# Django Rest - Custom JSON based on applied logic

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a custom JSON in Django rest framework. (The method used is serializers.ModelSerializer). I am not sure what approach is taken to achieve this.

Logic: Check for some data in a model and based on that data further calculation is done over another model. This will go on un till desired output is obtained. How do I setup my serializer and viewset.

```
class DataPointSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
    class Meta:
        model = DataPoint
        fileds = (what goes here ?)

    def to_representation(self,instance):
        model_one = model_one.objects.all()
        calculation using model_one
        model_two.objects.filter(by calculated data)
        construct JSON
        return  JSON
```

I would like to know the approach that would take to accomplish this task.

TK-01

```
   `def get_representation(self,instance): 
    data = []
    Shifts = Shift.objects.all()
    for shift in Shifts:
        data.append(shift.shift_name)
    return data`
```

TK-02

I'm trying to create something like this [Link](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#class-based-views) but instead of APIView I need it in serializers

Comment: Do you have to use a `ModelSerializer`? Given that the JSON output will be customised and not closely related to the fields of `DataPoint`, might it be better to extend `BaseSerializer` directly?

Comment: Will please check TK-02 in my question

Answer (score 0):

Serializer would be as follows:

```
class DataPointSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    representation = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = DataPoint
        fileds = ('representation',)

    def get_representation(self,instance):
        data = []
        model_one = model_one.objects.all()
        calculation using model_one
        model_two.objects.filter(by calculated data)
        construct JSON
        data.append(construct JSON)
        return data
```

Comment: Oh god, I knew about the custom function and I totally forgot that. Well I tried returning direct Model.objects.all() at the get_representaiton. It says cant be JSON serializable.

Comment: Maulik Patel: I tried this. shift model has id and shift_name. There are only three entries. But this get_representation returns a number of records from the Model attached to the Serializer at Meta Class. Each record has 3 entries from the Shift model in the output times the records of the model attached. Look for TK01 in the question for the code. when i return the Shift data it should appear only once in the output.